# finding web element using Protractor

Tags: protractor

```
<div _ngcontent-c13="" class="canvas-container" style="width: 100%;"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; pointer-events: none; visibility: hidden; z-index: -1;"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1;"><div style="position:absolute;width:1000000px;height:1000000px;left:0;top:0"></div></div><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1;"><div style="position:absolute;width:200%;height:200%;left:0; top:0"></div></div></div>
```

How can I identify this canvas element using protractor?

Also i want to read the tool tip value on this chart (doughnut chart in canvas element).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a lot of options. I would use css if is unique:

```
var canvassElement = element(by.css(".chartjs-render-monitor"));
```

or title:

```
var canvassElement = element(by.css("[title='Gender']"));
```

Or xpath:

```
.//div[@title='Gender']
```

or

```
.//div[@class='chartjs-render-monitor']
```

or using both if there are not unique on the dom:

```
 .//div[@title='Gender'][@class='chartjs-render-monitor']
```

Comment: Can you please check if xpath would work? I tried title yesterday but did not work. Used byall css for the class but when I iterate over it , it returned "trying to access 0 elements"

Comment: @user9919998 I updated the answer adding xpath locators

Comment: It doesnt work, unable to find the element... There is another widget on the same page with the class @class='chartjs-render-monitor'

Comment: @user9919998 Please try to use both attributes in one xpath, I updated the answer, check the last line.